# allOf for CompletionStage

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am trying to wait for a list of `CompletionStage`. What's the difference between the two approaches:

```
1. CompletableFuture.allOf(test.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

2. CompletableFuture.allOf(test.stream().map(CompletionStage::toCompletableFuture)
          .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
```

IntelliJ shows warning for the 1st that says expected type is `CompletableFuture[]` and not `CompletionStage[]`.
I wrote a small test and seems both behave the same. Is there a one preferred or "correct" way over the other?
Thanks. (Mainly looking to see if I am making a fundamental error or if one of the style is more correct way).

Comment: If `test` is a `Collection<CompletionStage<?>>` then the warning is simply that the array type may not be able to hold each element because not every `CompletionStage` is a `CompletableFuture`. If you know that every element is a `CompletableFuture` the you should be fine, though perhaps you should change `test` to a `Collection<CompletableFuture<?>>` to guarantee this. Your second approach maps each element to a `CompletableFuture` before collecting into an array so that will never have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is the safest IMO. As you say both work correctly, but `CompletionStage` is the super interface of `CompletableFuture` (in other words CompletableFuture is an implementation if CompletionStage), so doing a `toArray` as in the first method could theoretically cause a runtime exception if the actual type of the elements was not `CompletableFuture`.

On the other hand, the second approach leverages the API method `toCompletableFuture()` designed explicitly to interoperate from any `CompletionStage` implementation class to `CompletableFuture`.